# Extjs grid selection after store.load has incorrect data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In ExtJS 4.2
I have a grid with records with a remote load. I select a row in the grid and update that in the database.I am updating a record in the database and reloading the store with store.load(). After this occurs I can pause in debugger and check the store and it does indeed have the correct values. The same record is still selected however the following code:

```
var selectedRecords = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```

Is not getting the updated records. If I deselect and reselect it the record is refreshed but without doing so it still has the old values. Is there a way to refresh it.

I see a lot of posts about getting the rows to stay selected upon load, but that is not a problem for me it seems to be doing that on its own.

Comment: I believe ext js 4.2 have that bug.. you need to deselect and select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with the underlying the Selection Model. The 'selected' mixed collection does not get updated as Ext.selection.Model extends Ext.util.Observable and will be updated only when some event happens related to grid selection. If you do not want to deselect and then then select manually, or even register a callback on the store load, then try the following as workaround,

`var selectionArr = grid.selModel.selected;
selectionArr.replace(selectionArr.keys[0],grid.getStore().getById(selectionArr.keys[0]));`

Now try,

```
var selectedRecords = grid.selModel.getSelection();
```

Should work fine.

Comment: @tgreen : Mark it as answer if it's working for you.

Comment: Here is the code I used:
`activeGridpanel.store.addListener('load', function (store) {
                    var selectionArr = activeGridpanel.selModel.selected;
                    selectionArr.keys.forEach(function(key) {
                        selectionArr.replace(key, store.getById(key));
                    })
                })`

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the grid store after updating the value.

```
Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getView().refresh()
```

Comment: Refresh view won't fix the issue.

Comment: Yes I tried this and it didn't work. I think Surya may be correct